# Select rows randomly distributed around a given mean

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2008

I have a table that has a `value` field. The records have values somewhat evenly distributed between 0 and 100.

I want to query this table for `n` records, given a target mean, `x`, so that I'll receive a weighted random result set where `avg(value)` will be approximately `x`.

I could easily do something like

```
SELECT TOP n * FROM table ORDER BY abs(x - value)
```

... but that would give me the same result every time I run the query.

What I want to do is to add weighting of some sort, so that any record may be selected, but with diminishing probability as the distance from `x` increases, so that I'll end up with something like a normal distribution around my given mean.

I would appreciate any suggestions as to how I can achieve this.

Comment: Don't you have to use a random value somewhere if you want a random result set ? I can't see any random value in your question ... Maybe the value column is filled randomly?

Comment: @Run: I have to use random indeed! This is where I'm looking for suggestions on implementation. I don't want it to be just random, but weighted random, and I'm not sure what's the best way to achieve that.

Comment: Isn't regular random weighted at 0.5, so that avg(random) is about 0.5 ?

Comment: @run: 'tis! But how would i utilize this to achieve something like a normal distribution around x?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

<strike>why not use the RAND() function?</strike>

`SELECT TOP n * FROM table ORDER BY abs(x - value) + RAND()`

**EDIT**

Using Rand won't work because calls to RAND in a select have a tendency to produce the same number for most of the rows. Heximal was right to use NewID but it needs to be used directly in the order by

```
SELECT Top N value  
FROM  table  
ORDER BY
    abs(X - value) + (cast(cast(Newid()  as varbinary) as integer))/10000000000
```

The large divisor 10000000000 is used to keep the `avg(value)` closer to X while keeping the `AVG(x-value)` low.

With that all said maybe asking the question (without the SQL bits) on  https://stats.stackexchange.com/ will get you better results.

Comment: That'll give me a slight deviation from the strict selection in my example, but it'll add less than one to what i'd get from abs(x-value). I expect i'd have to multiply that by some fraction of the standard deviation, but i don't know exactly what parameters to use for a sensible result.

Comment: @David, simply changing the large divisor is going to change the weighting of the random number to the absolute difference from the desired mean.  So, using 1.0 is going to be more random and less "close the X" than 10000000000.0.  Then it all depends on the precision of your values (since you've already stated your range to be 0 to 100 and an even distribution) and the desired result standard deviation.

Comment: @chezy525 just want to point out that @David's comment was two hours ago. My edit was 32 minutes ago.

Comment: @conrad: I tried tampering with the large divisor, and I must say it's starting to look like what I'm looking for. The population will change over time, so I'm probably going to have to experiment with `count()` and `stdev()` to come up with a good divisor based on the actual population, but I believe I can manage on my own from here. +1 for now, and I'll examine this closer tomorrow :)

Comment: @conrad: Sorry for the late accept; holidays came in between. This is what I ended up going with. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

try

```
SELECT TOP n * FROM table ORDER BY abs(x - value),  newid()
```

or

```
select * from (
    SELECT TOP n * FROM table ORDER BY abs(x - value)
  ) a order by newid()
```

Comment: The selection of rows will be unaffected by this, except perhaps at the greatest values of `abs(x-value)`. If there are `n` rows with `value = x`, these will always be selected. I'm looking for something where `value = x-1` will be *almost* as likely to be selected as `value = x`.